# How to increase the image size without loosing quality using php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Right now I am creating a system like after edit the map using custom editor I need to print a map in 4 different large sizes but after customization when I am going to print in large size pixel is not good or printable and I am done with Editor now I need to help to create the image of large size to print. it must be a 300 dpi/ppi.

```
    <?php
// error_reporting(E_ALL);
// ini_set('display_errors', 1);

include '../../../wp-load.php';

$wp_content_path = wp_upload_dir();
// echo json_encode($wp_content_path['baseurl']);

$upload_dir = $wp_content_path['basedir']."/map-image-upload/";
$web_path = $wp_content_path['baseurl']."/map-image-upload/";
// echo $web_path;
// echo json_encode($upload_dir);

$w = $_POST['w'];
// echo json_encode($w);

$h = $_POST['h'];
// echo json_encode($h);

$img_data = $_POST['img_data'];
// echo json_encode($img_data);

$img_data = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img_data);
// echo json_encode($img_data);

$img_data = str_replace(' ', '+', $img_data);
// echo json_encode($img_data);

$data = base64_decode($img_data);
// echo json_encode($data);

$timestamp  = date("Y-m-d_H:i:s");
// echo json_encode($timestamp);

$file = $upload_dir  .$timestamp . ".png";
$large_img_path = $web_path.'large_'.$timestamp . ".png";
// here i set large img path in session
$_SESSION['large_img_path'] = $large_img_path;
$_SESSION['large_img_name'] = 'large_'.$timestamp . ".png";
// echo $large_img_path;

$myfile = fopen($file, "w") ;
$ch = fwrite($myfile, $data);
echo json_encode($ch);
fclose($myfile);

// i use imagick extension here
header('Content-type: image/png');
$image = new Imagick($file);
$image->adaptiveResizeImage($w,$h);
$image->writeImage($upload_dir.'large_'.$timestamp . ".png");
$image->clear();
$image->destroy();    

?>
```

I am using this code to generate the image

Comment: You can't magically create data that wasn't there before. If you enlargen an image, the ppi gets lower.

Comment: Why is this tagged angular?!

Comment: Could you please provide code samples, input file sample, etc... Please make sure that your question could be answered.

Comment: http://gismasoft.com/demo/map-editor/ this is the link of my work.

Comment: Real map is make here using leaflet js & mapbox

Answer (score 0):

I got the idea that it can be print by leaflet easyprint but now need to print it with originalState in bigger size. please let me know how is it posible.